how does the shape of a busbar affect current carrying capability
When working with a DC low voltage busbar (12V), how does the shape of the busbar (for the same cross section area) affect how much current the busbar can handle? If it matters, the material for this is aluminum.
How does an L shape compare to a flat bar? Can the current carrying capacity of an L be improved by squishing the two legs together to form a squished U?

Depends on current. It's about dissipating heat. L or flat - mattress in sense of how hot it gets.

I agree with TQQQ. The maximum current carrying capability of a conductor is limited by the maximum temperature or voltage drop you can tolerate. With a fixed cross section, greater surface area will give better heat dissipation, and allow for more current.

Surface area vs volume is the main thing.  Google "skin effect."

You may find the reasoning or calculation here relevant: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/705432/what-is-the-equivalent-awg-of-1-4-inch-soft-copper-tubing The example case (hollow vs. solid cylinder) turns out not to show much difference, but a much higher aspect ratio (i.e. thin, oddly shaped) section as here ought to show a notable difference.
